# angularjs state.go not working

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm trying to load a form on success of a delete request as follows

```
 $scope.delete = function (id) {

        if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this record?")) {

        var url = 'http://localhost/AwtCW2012002/api/restApiController/question.json/'+id;

        $http({
                  method: 'DELETE',
                  url: url,
                  })
            .success(function() {

                $state.go(app.addEditQuestion);

                 })
```

I have injected state in the controller

```
angular.module('app', []).controller('questionEditCtrl', ['$state','$scope', '$http', function ($state,$scope, $http) {
```

The error I get is

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/$injector/unpr?p0=%24stateProvider%20%3C-%20%24state%20%3C-%20questionEditCtrl
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost/AwtCW2012002/assets/js/angular.min.js:6:421
    at http://localhost/AwtCW2012002/assets/js/angular.min.js:42:203
    at Object.d [as get] (http://localhost/AwtCW2012002/assets/js/angular.min.js:40:175)
    at http://localhost/AwtCW2012002/assets/js/angular.min.js:42:265
    at d (http://localhost/AwtCW2012002/assets/js/angular.min.js:40:175)
    at Object.e [as invoke] (http://localhost/AwtCW2012002/assets/js/angular.min.js:40:445)
    at L.instance (http://localhost/AwtCW2012002/assets/js/angular.min.js:84:168)
    at v (http://localhost/AwtCW2012002/assets/js/angular.min.js:63:446)
    at g (http://localhost/AwtCW2012002/assets/js/angular.min.js:56:341)(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:111(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:84m.$apply @ angular.min.js:138(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:20e @ angular.min.js:40c @ angular.min.js:19zc @ angular.min.js:20be @ angular.min.js:19(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:303j @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2k.fireWith @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2m.extend.ready @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2J @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
gridView:77 GET http://localhost/AwtCW2012002/views/Images/BackgroundImage.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

app.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router', 'ngTable', 'ngRoute', 'ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap', 'questionAddCtrl', 'questionEditCtrl']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouteProvider, $routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
```

Comment: $state is part of ui-router, are you requiring it? doesn't seem so since `angular.module('app', []) ` has an empty dependency array...

Comment: Description
This error results from the $injector being unable to resolve a required dependency. To fix this, make sure the dependency is defined and spelled correctly.

Comment: Did you try this  $state.go('app.addEditQuestion');

Comment: Is your code minified ? If so could you try without the minification step, and see if it's working ?

Comment: No it's not minified.

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates a problem with your dependency injection.

From the [doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr) :

> This error results from the $injector being unable to resolve a required dependency. To fix this, make sure the dependency is defined and spelled correctly

You are supposed to configure the state provider like this :

```
angular.module('app', []).config(function($stateProvider) {
    // state handling goes here
});
```

See [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) for more infos.

Comment: I have included stateprovider in app.js